# Retrieve Names of Check Constraints Specific to a Column

Tags: postgresql, ddl, check-constraints, catalogs

PostgreSQL 12

*When I rename a column in a table, I would like to dynamically rename the matching check constraints as well.*

I have a hypothetical table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE hypothetical_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  some_col text,
  some_col_also text
);
```

There are constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE hypothetical_table ADD CONSTRAINT some_col_length_>_5 CHECK(char_length(some_col) > 5);

ALTER TABLE hypothetical_table ADD CONSTRAINT some_col_also_length_>_5 CHECK(char_length(some_col_also) > 5);
```

I do not know ahead of time what constraints a column may have. I do know that they are prefixed with the column name. But, like `some_col` constraint above, that prefix may match another column's (`some_col_also`).

When I rename a column in this table, I would like to rename the constraints as well, to match the new column name.

So, if I were to rename `some_col`, how can I select all of the check constraints associated with that column?

I have tried joining `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` with `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` ON `con.conkey = pga.attnum` (with `conkey` unnested), but that returns many constraints that are not associated with that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I select all of the check constraints associated with that column?

[`pg_constraint.conkey`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html) is an array column, so we join on `a.attnum = ANY(c.conkey)` **and** the oid of the relation additionally. Like:

```
SELECT conname -- pg_get_constraintdef(oid), *
FROM   pg_constraint c
JOIN   pg_attribute  a ON a.attrelid = c.conrelid     -- !
                      AND a.attnum   = ANY(c.conkey)  -- !
WHERE  c.conrelid = 'hypothetical_table'::regclass
AND    c.contype = 'c'  -- c = check constraint
AND    a.attname = 'some_col';
```

But I am doubtful of your overall objective:

> When I rename a column in a table, I would like to dynamically rename the matching check constraints as well.

`CHECK` constraints are always *table* constraints in Postgres and can reference any number of table columns. Even when formulated as column constraints! [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.9.5)

> #### Column Check Constraints
>
> The SQL standard says that `CHECK` column constraints can only refer
> to the column they apply to; only `CHECK` table constraints can refer
> to multiple columns. PostgreSQL does not enforce this restriction; it
> treats column and table check constraints alike.

So `some_col` and `some_col_also` can be referenced at the same time (multiple times). And both can be in the constraint name. I don't see how a completely dynamic solution can be bullet-proof, unless you can rely on a strict naming convention. (Can you really?). Is the following a reference to `some_col` or `some_col_also`?

```
some_col_also_is_a_fruit  -- oh, wait!
```

Rewriting the constraint expression itself also demands attention.

Comment: Thank you! some_col_also_is_a_fruit .... *sweat* ----

minor note, in my q i say "(with `conkey` unnested)" which is why I didn't get an err when joining to attnum. Is there a better way to phrase that?

Comment: @Avocado: Oh right, the unnested part slipped my attention. Scratching that bit.